# Confused about how Azure App Service Local Cache is useful, lacking any use cases

Tags: azure, app-service-environment

I've read all of the documentation about App Service Local Cache but I am struggling to see how it is useful. It claims to basically create a read-only copy of your Site directory, which for an MVC app is basically the whole app. But I can't find any information about use cases or why you'd want to do this.

I ask because it's been suggested that we move to implementing it, and I am trying to work out why we should do this.

I can see advantages if you do lots of reading/writing to disk but hardly any apps do that these days, we just use the database for everything, and logging goes directly to OMS.

Am I missing something major about this feature? To make my question non-vague, does this feature offer something useful for a simple MVC website that displays data from a database and writes back to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Even if your app doesn't perform a large amount of I/O operations, you can still benefit from using App Service Local Cache due to:

- Quicker app restarts (since files are local, latency to the shared network drive is removed). Helpful for app settings updates.
- Less application downtime if your app loses connectivity with the shared network drive (which causes restarts), which can happen during Azure update/patch operations on the underlying VM

More are discussed in the Channel 9 video for Local Cache https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-201-Azure-Web-App-Local-Cache-with-Cory-Fowler